# WebRtc CreatePeerConnectionFactory memory leak in example code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, webrtc

I'm having some issues using the WebRtc library. Everything works, but I see memory leaking over time. Through process of elimination I've tracked down the main source of the problem to the following example, which when run repeatedly causes memory to grow which is never de-allocated.

```
rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::PeerConnectionFactoryInterface> peer_connection_factory_ = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(
        nullptr /* network_thread */,
        nullptr /* worker_thread */,
        nullptr /* signaling_thread */,
        nullptr /* default_adm */,
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioEncoderFactory(),
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioDecoderFactory(),
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinVideoEncoderFactory(),
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinVideoDecoderFactory(), 
        nullptr /* audio_mixer */,
        nullptr /* audio_processing */);

    peer_connection_factory_.release();
```

The initialization code is actually taken from the webrtc example untouched ([see](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/peerconnection/client/conductor.cc) line 91). I'm not doing anything unusual. Currently using the branch-heads/72 version of webrtc, which should be stable as I understand. I'm also seeing memory growth in other versions, though have yet to verify if it's the exact same issue.

From what I understand a scoped_refptr should dispose and de-allocate it's resources whenever the last reference is cleared, which should be happening because there is only one copy of it. Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? I've also tried passing in nullptr for encoder/decoder factories, and the problem still seems to persist.

Many thanks